# error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and 'number'

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript2.0

I am using TypeScript 2.x, and lodash.

When I use

```
console.log(_.reduce([1, 2], (result, n) => result + n));    // 3
```

It gives me error:

> error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and
>   'number'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change to `result: number` will solve the issue.

```
console.log(_.reduce([1, 2], (result: number, n) => result + n));    // 3
```

TypeScript can only know `n` is number based on `[1, 2]`. But it does not know the type of `result` before it returns. So you need explicitly tell it.

For example,

```
console.log(_.reduce([1, 2], (result, n) => 'hi'));    // 'hi'
```

the type of `result` is string instead of number.

Comment: Thanks! My similar issue was that I used 'Number'. After I changed it to the lowercase 'number', it works =)